# windows 7 bat file leaves out parts of the command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a batch file with one command in it so that i dont have to remember the code. thought it would be simple however the code that it prints out when running it is not the code that is in the file. heres the only line in the file

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%f" .
```

I have run this code in the command prompt and it does what i want it to however when i put it in a batch file and run it this the code that is read by the cmd

```
C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\google music backup>movefromsubfolders
-D was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\google music backup>for /f "tokens=*" -D /s /b') do move "f" .
```

why is it screwing everything up? This is the first bat file i have ever attempted to write so i could possibly be doing something stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need double `%` when used in batch:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%%f"
```

Comment: @erikstagg - this is from `for` help message: `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable. Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.` It's due to how cmd.exe parse scripts , but as I have not the source code I cannot know the details :-)